# Unix Networking Programming - Program Stuck after Reading a Message from A Client

Tags: sockets, unix

I am currently writing a simple client and server program for both Windows and Unix. At this point in time I just wanted to create a simple client and server where the server would echo back the message to the client. I have got this to work in the windows environment but am having a very strange issue for the Unix environment. It seems after the message is received the server to print this out but then seems to get stuck. It will not attempt to send the message back to the client or even print another thing after it. I have attached the endless loop that I am using for the server. I have used the same code for the windows version and it seems to work 100% so i have no idea why this does not.

Ps This is my first post so sorry If i left anything out. I am also using Cygwin to run my Unix Code if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

```
 for(;;)
    {

        char buf[1024];
        int cc = recv(newsockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if (cc == 0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        buf[cc] = NULL;
        printf("message received: %s\n", buf);
        printf("This Never Prints!");
        send(newsockfd, buf, cc, 0 );
        memset(&buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richard,

It's possible that the second line doesn't print because `stdout` isn't flushed.
If your socket is non-blocking, perhaps the `send()` isn't working because an error in the subsequent `memset` corrupts the data before it's sent.

Try changing the last three statements to

```
printf("This should print!\n"); // Add a newline
fflush(stdout);                 // Flush the output for good measure
send(newsockfd, buf, cc, 0);    // Unchanged
memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf)); // buf is already an address.
```

Does that change the behavior?

Comment: Hey Adam. I just tired your suggestion however it did not change the behavior this bug has really got me stuck.

Comment: After the client sends the message to your code, does it close the socket?  That would make the `send()` fail.

Comment: No i do not close the socket on the client. It seems but that the program dies before the send is even reached however as i never see the print statement printf("This Never Prints!");.

Comment: Does it hang or exit?  Is it stuck in the `send()` or has it quit?  What happens if you add a printf() before the `exit(0)`?

Comment: The program does not exit it seems to hang after it prints the message that the server has received sample output would be 

   message received: test
Then the program will just hang there! So it does receive the message, prints it out then nothing. If i remove the printing of the message, the program still hangs. I have no idea why.

Comment: Update: I have gotta the program to work by making it sleep after it receives a message. Any Idea why this works?